# Get data using node.js from mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

I'm trying to get data from mongoDB.
In my schema year - is not unique so I did the following:

```
 app.get('/getBestByYear/:year', function(req, res) {    
Stud.find({}).where('year').in(req.params.year).where('grade').gt(89).exec(function(err,students){
            if(err) throw err;
            res.json(students);
         });
     })
```

I get an empty string.. What did i do wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if `.in()` can handle a non-array argument. Why not use `.equals(req.params.year)`? Also, I assume that the resulting query actually matches some documents?

Comment: yes of course! but it still gives me back an empty string

Comment: I would assume that Mongoose will cast properties to the right type, but just to be sure, can you try `.equals(Number(req.params.year))` (or perhaps `.where('year', req.params.year)`)? Also, try using [`.getQuery()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-getQuery) to see if the query that Mongoose is building works in the MongoDB shell.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
console.log(req.params.year);   // show to verify year is valid
Stud.find({year: {$in: [req.params.year]}, grade: {$gt: 89}}).exec(function (err, students) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(students);
})
```